# Making a custom menu, with an unknown number of items

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created XML code for how I'd like each element of the menu to look (this is for one element):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_border"
    android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Account name"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Balance: £61.43"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However there is an unknown number of items in the menu, so how would I generate this code in a class for n number of items in the menu?

Could I maybe put it in a file and call the file when it's needed repeatedly? I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recyclerview.
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

You need to create a class that will hold data for each element of your list, and create an Adapter that holds a list of items that you need.

Comment: Looks complicated, but I'll have a shot. Thanks.